# Get form id when button is clicked JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, flask

```html
<div class="card text-center" id="{{i[0]}}div">
    <div class="card-text">
        <p> {{i[3]}} / kg </p>
        <form>
            <input type="number" min=0 max=100 id="{{i[0]}}form" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="{{i[0]}}btn" onclick="addCart(this)">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this for loop that iterates over a list and create a form + button for each iteration.

Example:

```
list ["Papaya", "Banana"]
```

Then the code would have a form and button with id "Papayaform/Bananaform" and "Papayabtn and Bananabtn"

Now I'm trying to store the form value into a localstorage (I heard this is from HTML5) and the approach I am doing is by getting the id of `parentNode` of the button(this)

```
function addCart(e) {
    var x = e.parentNode.id
    document.body.append(x)
}
```

I was trying to append the id of the parent just to verify that it is getting the right input but there's no result (can't use console.log because I'm coding on mobile)

Is there any other approach to this?

I tried

```
<button onclick = "addCart(this.target.parentNode.id)">

this.target.parentNode.id
this.parentElement.id
```

Comment: I used alert() and it showed the id of the button on "this.id" but doesn't show anything on "this.parentNode.id" and "this.parentElement.id" trying to get the form id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your Html example isn't well-formed, the `</form>` closing tag should directly be after the the button closing element.
Secondly, in the example you did not give the form element an id attribute (must be `<form id="myformid">` .
I you do that, this Javascript will show the id of the form element:

```
<script>
    function addCart(btn) {
        alert(btn.parentElement.id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ It worked but what if I wanted to get the id of the <input>, I tried doing alert(btn.parentElement.firstChild.id) and alert(btn.previousSibling.id) but it returns undefined.

Comment: well, you fill in the id of the input in your iteration, might as well fill in the same id in your javascript call: onclick="addCart(this, '{{i[0]}}form')"

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add it is a `data attribute` on the button, then retrieve it with `getAttribute`.

Traversing html is problematic and can break with simple structure changes.

See snippet below, in your case it would be:

```
<button onclick="console.log(this.getAttribute('data-formId'))" data-formId="{{i[0]}}div">
    Click me
</button>
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(this.getAttribute('data-formId'))" data-formId="10">
Click me to console log form Id which is 10
</button>
```